# Python type convertion based on string

Tags: python, types

How can I write this code so it works for every type given?

```
def set_val_type(val, val_type):
    if val_type == 'bool':
        return bool(val)
    elif val_type == 'int':
        return int(val)
```

Comment: consider using `isinstance()` for type checking

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @pault I'll bet it's part of a home-grown ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def set_val_type(val, val_type):
    return eval(val_type + '({})'.format(val))
```

As much as this seems to be what you are looking for, [using eval is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It seems like an XY problem as commented before by @pault

Comment: [Why is using `eval` a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/5858851)?

Comment: I agree, it's probably an XY problem as you commented before, just posted it because it seemed to be exactly what Koby 27 was looking for.

Comment: you may want to also add the comment as a part of your answer to make it more well rounded. For Koby's sake and others like him who look up this question later.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of all the types you need to process.

```
def set_val_type(val, val_type):
    funcs = {'int': int, 'bool': bool}
    return funcs[val_type](val)
```

Comment: A `funcs.get(val_type)(val)` might work more favorably especially if we are uncertain of the input to give it a little extra handling.  Though I'm not sure what to put in place of the default.

Comment: @Idlehands: [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/5987).

Comment: I understand that concept in Python, but thanks for sharing it.  I'm just not sure how a `KeyError` might be more helpful, unless the whole `set_val_type` is expected to be wrapped in a `try` block.  Though I must say the nature of OP's question is very... questionable already so I shall hold my tongue.

Comment: @Idlehands I admit my reply was a bit short and cryptic. What I really meant was that raising an exception is a totally appropriate thing to do when given invalid input, and I don't think the type of the exception matters much.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using `eval`, and presuming you are only using builtin types, you can use a `getattr()` on the builtins module (if you want to make sure you don't call any functions, you can perform an `isinstance(user_provided_type_here, type)` before.

To allow any type in global scope, use `globals()[user_provided_type_name]`

Complete example:

```
import builtins

def set_val_type(val, val_type);
    user_type = getattr(builtins, val_type)  # possibly replace with globals()[val_type]
    if not isinstance(user_type, type):
        raise TypeError(f'{user_type} is no a type.')
    return user_type(val)
```

Why **not** to use `eval()` (with *untrusted* user input):

```
def set_val_type(val, val_type):
    return eval(val_type + '({})'.format(val))

evil_val_type = 'bool'
evil_val = 'exec("import os\\nos.chdir(os.path.sep)\\nprint(os.getcwd())")'

print(set_val_type(evil_val, evil_val_name))
'False'  # yes, this actually works error-free
```

With this level of access, one is just a `subprocess.Popen` / `os.system` from *very* bad news.
That said, if your user input is trusted, using `eval()` is <del>not</del> less problematic.